Make a SSL cert file available in worker node in Dataflow using Python SDK
I need to connect to a Kafka cluster using SSL certificates.
I have tried deploying the job by keeping the SSL files in GCS bucket, but that doesn't work.
I also tried to copy the file from GCP to a "/tmp/" location, assuming that file will be downloaded in the worker node, but to my surprise, it got downloaded in the local server from where I am submitting the job.
How do I make my SSL files available to the dataflow worked nodes?
I am using Python SDK.
Code Snippet:
msg_kv_bytes = pipeline | "read file" >> ReadFromKafka(
     consumer_config={
      "bootstrap.servers": "IP:PORT",
      "group.id": "xyz",
      "default.api.timeout.ms" : "300000",
      "security.protocol": "SSL",
        "ssl.truststore.location": "gs://bucket-name/myp12file.p12",
        "ssl.truststore.password": "***",
        "ssl.truststore.type": "PKCS12",
        "ssl.keystore.type": "PKCS12",
        "ssl.keystore.password": "***",
        "ssl.keystore.location": "gs://my-bucket/myp12file.p12",
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
    },
    topics=["my-topic"],
    key_deserializer='org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer',
    value_deserializer='org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer',
    start_read_time=None,
    max_num_records = 10,
    max_read_time=None,
    commit_offset_in_finalize=False,
    timestamp_policy='ProcessingTime',
    with_metadata=True,
    expansion_service ='localhost:8088'
  )


Do you use https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.kafka.html? If so, how do you configure consumer_config now? You might need to put that SSL files into your Python customer container.

I have added the way I am trying to read .p12 file from GCS bucket. But I get an error in Dataflow console saying "NoFIleFound" exception

I am not sure it supports the GCS bucket.
